# Should the cold water supply be constantly open for hot water heating system?

Tags: plumbing, heating

I just flushed out my baseboard heating system and refilled it with new water. I am wondering, should the cold water supply to the system stay open or should it be a closed loop until flushed again at another date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed.

Two reasons - main one, you need to know if it's leaking. A properly functioning system should not need "make up water" on a regular basis.

The other, related reason - if the system is leaking and constantly taking in new water, it's also taking in new dissolved oxygen in that water - and 99.9% of hot water heating systems are built with a mixture of copper and iron parts (or all iron parts) that will rust terribly if continuously supplied with oxygen. A non-leaking system rusts out what oxygen is in the water, and then stops rusting. Every time you add new water it rusts more; so the less you add new water, the less the interior of the system rusts.

Comment: Not to mention the build up of scale from new calcium in the make-up water, if it's hard...

Comment: With the fill valve open, and there is not a backflow preventer installed (more common than you think) you could contaminate your drinking water if the incoming water pressure were to drop.

Comment: I've already answered this but if you have a backflow preventer along with a 12-15 PSI regulator installed, would it make sense to leave it on in that case?

Comment: No. Read the answer again. The answer does not assume that you are missing either of those devices.